# Urdu typing in WinEdt (using Miktex)

Tags: xetex, miktex, winedt

This may sound duplicate question but i am really new to the TeX system. I have gone through following steps:

- Installed MiKTeX 2.9
- Installed WinEdt 9.0
- WinEdt automatically picked up Miktex and I was able to open sample TeX files
- Updated MiKTeX to download the `polyglossia` package

Now I want to use Urdu in my document. I used the following example

```
%! xelatex mal-urdu.tex
% To download: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=Scheherazade#1fd0063a
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setmainlanguage{english}
 \setotherlanguage{urdu}
  \newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Amiri} % or   
  Scheherazade after installing the font
   \begin{document}
    Text before. \texturdu{ وہ کتاب ہے۔ میں جا رہا ہوں} Text after.
    \end{document}
```

When I compile this file, I get the following errors

```
* XeTeX is required to compile this document 
* Sorry
```

After selecting xelatex, I recieved the following error log

```
Running hbf2gf.exe...
hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.3)
Couldn't find `I.cfg'
miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font ICU.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Amiri" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

 l.10 ...ipt=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
                                    % or Scheherazade after i...Running miktex-         
makemf.exe...
mik   tex-makemf: The ICU source file could not be found.

Running hbf2gf.exe...


hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.3)
 Couldn't find `I.cfg'

miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font ICU.
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'Amiri' does not contain script 'Arabic'.
*************************************************
! Cannot use \XeTeXOTcountlanguages with nullfont; not an OpenType Layout font.
<argument> ...eXOTcountlanguages \l_fontspec_font 
                                              \l_fontspec_script_int 
l.10 ...ipt=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
% or Scheherazade after i...? 
Process has been terminated ...
```

I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: No: all engines are already installed. Probably your editor is configured to compile with (pdf)LaTeX by default, and it's only a matter of editor configuration. Which one do you use?

Comment: use in the tex-pdf-menu the entry xelatex to compile.

Comment: You don't have the Amiri font; use a font that supports the Arabic script you have on your system.

Comment: downloaded Scheherazade and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the toolbar a dropdown menu lets you choose the default compiler: the default is `pdflatex`
[image]

and clicking on the small black triangle on the right, you can select XeLaTeX, obtaining this default:

[image]

Comment: i changed the psflatex to xelatex and got the stack trace as shown in my question. please enlighten.